# ActiveMQ and Java routes

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm new to ActiveMQ (version 5.9.1) and Apache Camel. I'm experimenting about a couple of routes. I wrote them in Java, then packed in a .jar and deployed on %ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/lib. In my custom foo-activemq.xml I added a camelContext tag with a package child tag. Here is my relevant .xml

```
...
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <package>edu.foo.amq.camel</package>
</camelContext>
...
```

And here are my two routes:

```
package edu.foo.amq.camel;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class NumberRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("jms:queue:number.queue")
      .marshal("UTF-8")
      .choice()
      .when(header("readyToGo").isNotEqualTo(true))
        .to("jms:queue:big.number.queue");
    }
}
```

and

```
package edu.foo.amq.camel;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class BigNumberRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("jms:queue:big.number.queue")
    .marshal("UTF-8")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
            arg0.getIn().setHeader("readyToGo", true);
            System.out.println(arg0.getIn().getBody(
                    String.class));
            }
        })
        .to("jms:queue:number.queue");
    }
}
```

When I start my ActiveMQ broker I can see `... Total 0 routes, of wich 0 is started.`. If I look at the ActiveMQ web console I can se the queues `number.queue` and `big.number.queue` up and running but my java routes don't. What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**
I remove the camelContext tag from my foo-activemq.xml configuration file and add the import tag instead:

```
...
<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
<import resource="foo-camel.xml"/>
...
```

Here is my foo-camle.xml configuration file, I largely use the %ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/examples/conf/camel.xml file. I put this file into %ACTIVEMQ_HOME%/conf:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>edu.foo.amq.camel</package>
</camelContext>
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://amq-broker?create=false"/>
        <property name="userName" value="${activemq.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but the result is the same: ActiveMQ says no routes

Answer (score 2):

The Camel configuration XML file must be added to the `activemq.xml` configuration file:

```
<import resource="foo-activemq.xml" />
```

**EDIT:**

What else?

- Rename `foo-activemq.xml` to the default `activemq.xml`
- Verify again if your `jar` is really in the `lib` directory (I am sure you have done that already)
- Add a simple test route to `foo-camel-xml` and check in the log file if this route is loaded, e.g.

  ```
  <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" >
      <package>edu.foo.amq.camel</package>
      <route>
          <from uri="direct:start" />
          <log message="${body}" />
      </route>
  </camelContext>
  ```

Comment: Hello, thankyou for your reply. I follow your suggest but still no route on my broker. I update my question.

Comment: @Francesco I added some additional hints. Hope it helps.

Comment: I manage to get work all the stuff using xmlspring defined routes and Java Processor bean. I miss how to use routes by Java bean. Any tip about java bean routes in activemq?